# warning message at the prompt

Tags: warnings, simulation, wave, modelsim

I'm trying to simulate a testbench. I'm not getting the waveforms also i'm getting the following warning message at the prompt. Is it because of the=is warning that my code does not simulate?

```
** Warning: (vsim-WLF-5000) WLF file currently in use: vsim.wlf
#           File in use by:   Hostname:   ProcessID: 0
#           Attempting to use alternate WLF file "./wlftazxa4k".
# ** Warning: (vsim-WLF-5001) Could not open WLF file: vsim.wlf
#           Using alternate file: ./wlftazxa4k
run
```

I'm also includng my testbench as follows:

```
    module dec_tb;
    reg [63:0] FROM_IF_ID;
    reg CLK;
    wire [117:0] TO_ID_HMIC;
    integer k=0;
    inst_decode id(.from_if_id(FROM_IF_ID),.clk(CLK),.to_id_hmic(TO_ID_HMIC));

    initial 
     begin
       $monitor($time,"clk=%b, fifid=%b, tidhm=%b",CLK,FROM_IF_ID,TO_ID_HMIC);
       $display("qf");
       CLK= 0;
       FROM_IF_ID[35:32]=4'b1100; 
       FROM_IF_ID[63:36]=28'b0000_10000_00100_01000_00010_0001;
     end

    always 
     begin
     #10 CLK= ~CLK;
     end
    always @(posedge CLK)
      begin
      $display (" TO_ID_HMIC= %b", TO_ID_HMIC);
      FROM_IF_ID[k] =~FROM_IF_ID[k]; 
      k=k+1;
      #500 $finish;
      end
    endmodule
```

Answer (score 3):

If that's the only message, then the simulation ran, and you can find the waves in the specified alternate file (`wlftazxa4k`).

If you want to fix the problem so the waves show up in vsim.wlf, here are a few things to try:

- Make sure you don't have any stray modelsim processes running
- Make sure you don't have `vsim.wlf` open in a waveform viewer
- Delete `vsim.wlf` manually and rerun

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also. As it turns out, the directory that my vsim files were located in was full (school partition, 600mb allowed space). After clearing out some old files i had lying around, the program worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your your quiz:

1. Run you simulation
2. Quit your simulation with gui or command: `quit -sim`
3. Goto step 1 and have fun.

You can remove cache file create by modelsim.